# arrays and pointers HOW?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, classification

So i have been writing a code which it reads a [20][20] data to the computer and then it rounds the data UP to 3 decimal places. later on, it takes average of the data based on the ranges from 0 to 2.5. everything works fine until when i want to write a code which can create a classification map where it can display values from 1 to 10 and it shows if a value in the data is within the ranges and if it is greater than or smaller than the average it shows the desired number. i think by an example it makes more sense to anyone here.
for example in my [20][20] data, the first number is 0.211, it is between 0.0 and 0.5; then the average for the values between 0.0 and 0.5 is 0.241, then in my classification map i want to show the number 1 for this value showing that the number was in between the range 0 and 0.5 and it was also smaller that the average for the range which was calculated to be 0.241. For the next number if everything is the same except that the number is greater than the average 0.241, then it shows the number 2 in the classification map. if my next number is to be 0.611 then it is between ranges 0.5 to 1.0 and if it is smaller than the average calculated for this range which is calculated to be 0.727 then is shows 3 in the classification map.

my code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// Declare constants
// Data size
#define MAX_ROWS 20
#define MAX_COLUMNS 20
#define LOW_ERROR 0.0
#define HIGH_ERROR 2.5
#define MAX_RANGE 6
#define MAX_DISPLAY_VALUE 10

// Main entry point for the program
int main(void) 
{
// Decalred variables
int rowIndex = 0;
int columnIndex = 0;

//Stores the  data and maps
double rawData[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS]; // 2-dimensional array to store our raw data
double roundedValue[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS]; // 2-dimensional array to store our rounded data
int classificationMap[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS]; // 2-dimensional array to store our classification map
int displayValue[MAX_DISPLAY_VALUE] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };

//Stores the range data
float rangeValue[MAX_RANGE] = { 0.0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5 }; // Set up the range bounds
int i, num = 0;
float total[MAX_RANGE] = { 0 }, average[MAX_RANGE] = { 0 };

// Print out the rawdata array
printf(" --- RAW DATA ---\n");
for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < MAX_ROWS; rowIndex++) 
{
    // Read up until the last value
    for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < MAX_COLUMNS; columnIndex++) 
    {
        printf("%.9lf ", rawData[rowIndex][columnIndex]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

// Print out the roundup data array
printf(" --- ROUNDED DATA ---\n");
for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < MAX_ROWS; rowIndex++)
{
    // Read up until the last value
    for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < MAX_COLUMNS; columnIndex++)
    {
        if (rawData[rowIndex][columnIndex] < LOW_ERROR)
        {
            roundedValue[rowIndex][columnIndex] = LOW_ERROR;
            printf("%.3f ", LOW_ERROR);
        }
        else if (rawData[rowIndex][columnIndex] > HIGH_ERROR)
        {
            roundedValue[rowIndex][columnIndex] = HIGH_ERROR;
            printf("%.3f ", HIGH_ERROR);
        }
        else
        {
            roundedValue[rowIndex][columnIndex] = ceil(rawData[rowIndex][columnIndex] * 1000.0) / 1000.0;
            printf("%.3f ", ceil(rawData[rowIndex][columnIndex] * 1000.0) / 1000.0);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
//Calculate and store the averages for each range
printf(" --- RANGE TABLE ---\n");
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < MAX_ROWS; rowIndex++)
    {
        for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < MAX_COLUMNS; columnIndex++)
            if (roundedValue[rowIndex][columnIndex] > rangeValue[i] && roundedValue[rowIndex][columnIndex] <= rangeValue[i + 1])
            {
                total[i] = total[i] + roundedValue[rowIndex][columnIndex];
                num++;
            }

    }

    average[i] = total[i] / num;
    printf("%.3f \n", average[i]);
    total[i] = 0;
    average[i] = 0;
    num = 0;
}

//Create the classification map
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < MAX_ROWS; rowIndex++)
    {
        for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < MAX_COLUMNS; columnIndex++)
            if (roundedValue[rowIndex][columnIndex] > rangeValue[i] && roundedValue[rowIndex][columnIndex] <= rangeValue[i + 1] && roundedValue[rowIndex][columnIndex] <= average[i])
            {
                classificationMap[rowIndex][columnIndex] = displayValue[i];
            }
            else if (roundedValue[rowIndex][columnIndex] > rangeValue[i] && roundedValue[rowIndex][columnIndex] <= rangeValue[i + 1] && roundedValue[rowIndex][columnIndex] > average[i])
            {
            classificationMap[rowIndex][columnIndex] = displayValue[i + 1];
            }

    }
printf("--- CLASSIFICATION MAP ---\n");
for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < MAX_ROWS; rowIndex++)
{
    //Read up until the last value
    for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < MAX_COLUMNS; columnIndex++)
    {
        printf("%d ", classificationMap[rowIndex][columnIndex]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}



// Exit
return 0;
}
```

My problem is that i have two arrays one is for displayVlaues and the other one is for rangeVlaues. when i print my code for the classification map i get my numbers up to only 5.
Any idea why? i am a C beginner and this might be a silly question so i am sorry!

Comment: When you create the classification map you use `[i]` on some arrays that have less than 10 elements.

Comment: the posted code, in several places, is accessing beyond the upper bound of some arrays,  This is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: regarding this kind of expression `ceil(rawData[rowIndex][columnIndex] * 1000.0) / 1000.0`   This does NOT round the number.   Rather it gets the next whole number, then multiplies that whole number by 1   (1000. /1000. = 1)